# Is there a graph that his group nodes

Tags: graph-theory

$k\ge20$ integer.

Is there a graph that has group nodes $V={v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_k}$ so that the degree of node $v_i$ is ${2k+1\choose i}$ for $1\le i\le k$. If No-prove. If Yes-give an example.
thanks!

*I forgot to mention that the graph maybe has multiple edges

Comment: Of course not, because ${2k+1\choose 1}>k-1$.

Comment: Perhaps the graph need not be simple?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you allow edges in parallel and/or loops, consider that:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{k} \binom{2k+1}{i} = \sum_{i=0}^{k} \binom{2k+1}{2k+1 -i} = \sum_{i=k+1}^{2k+1} \binom{2k+1}{i}$$

But we also know:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{2k+1} \binom{2k+1}{i} = \sum_{i=0}^{k} \binom{2k+1}{i} + \sum_{i=k+1}^{2k+1} \binom{2k+1}{i} = 2^{2k+1}$$

So you have:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{k} \binom{2k+1}{i} = \frac{2^{2k+1}}{2}$$

And thus:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{k} \binom{2k+1}{i} = 2^{2k}-1$$

What does this tell you about the graph? See the [Handshaking Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma).